# Exception handling in spring batch job 3

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new in spring batch job 3. I have written a code where i am reading a file, processing it and writing in a new file. Now, this is running perfectly. But when file name is incorrect then spring gives its own exception. I want to handle this exception by giving user readable messages.

So,how can I handle exception (eg. file not found) in spring batch job 3.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. There's surely resources and tutorials, just google them, maybe you could try with some of the tutorials and if you have a more concrete question just post it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find anywhere that 's  why i asked here. If you can guide me any tutorial it will be nice.

Comment: Take a look of to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this kind of question is actually off-topic. Honestly I don't know much about spring batch, but I've just googled a bit and these 2 look ok as a starting point: [1](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/spring-batch-tutorial.html#error), [2](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/). Just as an example. Thanks.

Comment: afaik you can't change the exceptions from the inside, but you can change e.g. the ExitStatus and give it a meaningful message